# How to debug `Job arguments to Rollbar::Delay::Sidekiq do not serialize to JSON safely` warning from Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, deprecation-warning, rollbar

I have the following log from my ruby on rails app.

```bash
- NoMethodError (undefined method `encode` for nil:NilClass
-       redirect_to "/post_message#token=#{@secret.encode(token)}"
-                                                 ^^^^^^^):
- app/controllers/canvas_test_controller.rb:126:in `redirect_token`
- I, [2023-08-22T10:21:40.643432 #25]  INFO -- : [3cc2fde2-4da9-451b-973e-15c8fe93d91d] [Rollbar] Scheduling item
- pid=25 tid=3a1x WARN: Job arguments to Rollbar::Delay::Sidekiq do not serialize to JSON safely. This will raise an error in
- Sidekiq 7.0. See https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices or raise an error today
- by calling `Sidekiq.strict_args!` during Sidekiq initialization.
```

I intentionally raised this error to test rollbar but why am i getting a Sidekiq warning:
`Job arguments to Rollbar::Delay::Sidekiq do not serialize to JSON safely.`

I applied Sidekiq's best practices to my code but this error seems to be coming from
`Rollbar::Delay::Sidekiq`.

I am using the followig gems:

```rb
rollbar (3.4.0)
sidekiq (6.5.6)
```

I tried updating both sidekiq and rollbar to the latest version but still same warning persist. How do i debug this?

Comment: Did you try changing the config to `Sidekiq.strict_args!` and see the exact issue Sidekiq is complaining about? What does your code creating the job look like?

Comment: You may want to check out [this issue](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/issues/1077).  There are some suggested fixes there.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @cschroed. I looked into rollbar's documentation https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/sidekiq-integration and adding `config.async_json_payload = true` to rollbar's config solved the issue.